# How to get ui-router state params?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a food planner that allows the user to input their meals. They access it through fixed monday-sunday buttons, and the url looks like:

```
#/planner/Monday/add-meal
```

I am trying to create new objects to an array that takes:

```
  $scope.meal = {
    day: [THE DAY IN THE URL],
    title: '',
    description:''
  };
```

Do I need to use $root service?

I'm using the Ionic framework. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "$root service"?

Answer (score 1):

In your router, use the following URL for the state:

```
/planner/:dayOfWeek/add-meal
```

Then, in your controller, inject `$stateParams`:

```js
.controller("TheController", ["$scope", "$stateParams", function ($scope, $stateParams) {

  $scope.meal = {
    day: $stateParams.dayOfWeek,
    title: '',
    description:''
  };

}]);
```

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters.